# how to load the kendoui grid with image from the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I created a table in my mysql database.I have Image column,combobox column,radiobutton column,link column is there.I am using kendoui grid.

I have a calender field .i gave the type as "date", it is working fine.

i am able to load the data from database but the image field is not loading,what is the type for the image field?

in the link column, it is taking as a string,what i want is that,if i click on the link,it has to go for the particular webpage. what is the type for link field in the kendoui grid?

and I want the type for radio button and combo box.

can any one help me..

Answer (score 1):

If you store images as byte array, I think you need to create some url which returs image by its id manually.

But if you store direct link then you can handle it like this:

Just use column templates for this.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns:
    {
        { 
            field: "imagelink", 
            title: "Image", 
            template: "<a href='${ imagelink }>Click me</a>"
        },
        { 
            field: "imageid", 
            title: "Image2", 
            template: "<a href='/myUrlToGetImageById?id=${ imagelink }>Click me</a>"
        }    
    }
...
```

You can use all fields at the template. Not just the current column has.